# onClick function of button that is in a datagrid row - extjs

Tags: datagrid, extjs, extjs3

I have put a button on a dataGrid with the following code

column is;

```
var avaliableAction = {
header : "Action",
width : 120,
sortable : true,
align : "left",
dataIndex : 'status',
renderer : statusRenderer
};
```

data grid is;

```
var mainJobsGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store : jobsStore,
    columns : [ avaliableAction ],
    viewConfig : {
            forcefit : true
    },
    title : 'Data Mart Jobs',
    height : 198,
    width : 540,
    frame : true
});
```

renderer is;

```
function statusRenderer(value, id, r) {
    var START_ICON = '/etlscheduler/resources/images/start-icon.png';
    var STOP_ICON = '/etlscheduler/resources/images/stop-icon.png';
    if (value == "STOPPED") {
        return "<input type='button' class='btnStart' onClick='doStart(); '>";
    } else if (value == "RUNNING" || value == "WAITING") {
        return "<input type='button' class='btnStop' onClick='doStop();'>";
    }
};
```

and

```
function doStop() { ... }
function doStart() { ... }
```

The problem is that when I click the button exception occurs as "doStop is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you need to define the function

```
function doStop() { ... }
```

Comment: I've already defined it, all of the code above is on the same javascript file

Comment: thought that would be too easy :), thanks for updating code.  Maybe you should post the bntStop and btnStart classes too.  Does it ever show "STOPPED" and does doStart work?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and it wasn't a typo! i have noticed that the implementation of the called function works only if it was outside the  "Ext.onReady(function(){}".

If someone faces the same problem, i have solved it through writing the function as following:

Ext.the_function = function(){...}

instead of :

var the_function = function(){...}

This would fix the problem and it will work wherever you put it!